# Show / Hide different divs Onclick in different classes

Tags: php, jquery, html, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to call different divs to show or hide, when I click on a hyperlink with a class. The problem is, I can't get one to disappear when the other hyperlink is clicked. I know its in .Toggle, but I can't figure out how to do it. Thanks for your help in advance.

HTML:

```
<div class="menu-container">
         <div class="left">
       <?php if (have_rows('menu_items')): 
         while (have_rows('menu_items')): the_row(); ?>
         <a href="#/"><div id="<?php the_sub_field('menu_id'); ?>" class="menu-item"><?php the_sub_field('menu_item'); ?></div></a>

       <?php endwhile;
     endif; ?>
   </div>
     <div class="food-container">
       <?php if (have_rows('food_items')):
         while (have_rows('food_items')): the_row(); ?>
       <div id ="<?php the_sub_field('food_id'); ?>">
         <div class="food-item-container">
      <div class="food"> <h3><?php the_sub_field('food_name'); ?></h3>
       <?php the_sub_field('food_description'); ?>
     </div><div class="price"><?php the_sub_field('price'); ?></div>
   </div>
       <div class="clear"></div>
       <?php endwhile;
     endif; ?>
       </div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $("#menu-item1").click(function() {
            $("#food_id1_1, #food_id1_2, #food_id1_3, #food_id1_4, #food_id1_5, #food_id1_6").fadeToggle();

        });
        $("#menu-item2").click(function() {
            $("#food_id2_1, #food_id2_2, #food_id2_3, #food_id2_4, #food_id2_5, #food_id2_6").fadeToggle();

        });
    });
    </script>
```

Here is the url ---> http://dev.the-end-zone.com/menu/

Comment: Check this link:- http://www.randomsnippets.com/2011/04/10/how-to-hide-show-or-toggle-your-div-with-jquery/

Comment: Can you create a fiddle instead of providing a link that doesn't work

Comment: Sorry about that....I don't know why the link doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to toggle individual menu items as well as when the other is toggled you want to hide the previous menu items if they were open

You can do something like this:

Sample HTML:

```
<a id="a1" href="javascript:;">CLick 1</a>
<div id="f1" class='fdiv'>F1</div>
<br/>
<a id="a2" href="javascript:;">CLick 2</a>
<div id="f2" class='fdiv'>F2</div>
```

jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#a1").click(function(){
    $("#f2").hide();
    $("#f1").toggle();
  });

  $("#a2").click(function(){
   $("#f1").hide();
   $("#f2").toggle();
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sandenay/L06LtLfz/

Comment: Thanks, but problem is that the menu items are loaded dynamically into a single div that needs to show when one menu item is clicked. I got the first menu items to load with "Appetizers"....but when I hit Salads, the salad choice load under the Appetizers choices, instead of taking over that div.